# OleDB to ODBC bridge - Not the other way

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oledb

Since Sql Server CE 4 does not have an ODBC driver, but does support oledb, this means we cannot connect something like MS Access to it. But this made me wonder - is there not an OLEDB to ODBC bridge out there somewhere? I know the opposite direction exists, but I cannot find one that goes this direction. Also, would there be insurmountable difficulties in creating such an animal?

Comment: I am not sure, but wouldn't it be possible to connect to an OleDB data source via ADO in Access? You might not easily be able view / edit the data in the form of linked tables, but at least in a VBA environment you could retrieve the recordsets.

Comment: @nicholas, yes you can from vba code, but you cant link tables.. I should specify, that's what I'm really needing/wanting to do.

Comment: Well I don't have any OleDB data source to test with, but might I suggest trying to manually define the linked tables in VBA using the CurrentDB.TableDefs collection. Perhaps with a custom defined connection string it may be possible to link to OleDB.

Comment: Whoops. Scratch that suggestion. Looks like OleDB is not one of the [supported connection types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243197(v=office.12).aspx) in linked tables after all.

Comment: surprising isnt it? good find on that list though